# Should I have a catch in this promise code?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, es6-promise

One reads this [article here from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) on how to use promises.

I clearly check for errors in my database query but should I also be using `catch` after `then` when I use the database?

**Database**

```
const pool = mysql.createPool(helper.getMySQL());

const queryMaker = (query) => {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
      error ? reject(error) : resolve(results, fields);
    });
  });
};

exports.selectAllDomains = () => {
  const query = `some mysql query`;
  return queryMaker(query);
};
```

**Use Case**

```
router.route('/items').get((req, res) => {
    MySQL.selectAllDomains().then((results) => {
        if(req.user){
          results[results.length] = req.user;
        }
        res.status(200).json(results);
    });
    // Should I have a catch here?  
});
```

Comment: If something goes wrong with `MySQL.selectAllDomains()` then you will not catch that error and Node will crash (in some version in the future), for now you do just get an unhandled rejection warning.

Comment: Should not this line handle it ? `error ? reject(error) : resolve(results, fields);`

Comment: Well.. when you call reject(error) you are not handling it. You are simply just propagating the error down the chain.

Comment: I find it annoying that I have to put error handling code for my database in the application file that calls it.  There is no way around this I take it.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can handle it in your DB file too. Where you have `return queryMaker(query)` you could add a catch statement there. You also don't have to call reject. If there is an error you could resolve with an empty promise or something else.

Comment: Then there is a chance that the caller will get `cannot get property of undefined` it's good practice to let the caller deal with the error handling

Comment: Could I add a catch in the `queryMaker` function?

Comment: But it is so repetitive, ideally checking for a database error should be done in one place only.

Comment: By ideally I mean that the code base would be reduced and easier to maintain.

Comment: Of course, you need to handle errors. Otherwise they will be... unhandled. This will result in UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in console and pending request on error.

Answer (score 1):

When there is a DB error the promise will return an error and this error will not enter into the then callback that you have. So since you are handling an HTTP request if there is a DB error then the client will not receive a response and will eventually timeout.

I suggest that you do use a catch because then if there is a DB error you can send a proper error message to the client with something like `res.status(500).send(error);`

Answer (score 1):

> Should I have a catch in this promise code?

Yes, you should.  If your database call reject its promise, then you never respond to the http request which will just sit there with no response getting sent and will eventually time out.  In addition to failing to send a response to the client in a timely fashion, this also consumes a server resource for the duration of the timeout.  If there's some temporary database failure, this can potentially cause a lot of requests to pile up until they timeout which could exhaust resources on the server.

Instead, you need to catch the error and immediately return an error response to the http request.

```
router.route('/items').get((req, res) => {
    MySQL.selectAllDomains().then((results) => {
        if(req.user){
          results[results.length] = req.user;
        }
        res.status(200).json(results);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send("database internal error");
    });
});
```

> If I were to guess, I'd say no because I'm not doing something error prone in the then method.

It is not safe to assume that there will never be an error from your DB calls.  Robust programming anticipates that there could be an error there in some conditions (disk error, database disk volume offline, connection pool problem, query error, etc...) and handles that error appropriately.

Comment: Assuming an express route, the catch statement could be simplified further by inheriting default error handling with `next()`, for example `.catch(next)`

Comment: @Johnmorsey - Does this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.  If not, then please indicate what is not yet answered.